# How to get page number in PrimeNg DataGrid in angular 2?

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using PrimeNg dataGrid in my angular2 project. Can anyone tell me how to get the page number?

Comment: <p-dataGrid [value]="questions" [paginator]="true" [rows]="1">
      <p-header>
           List of Questions
      </p-header>
      <template let-question pTemplate="item" let-i="index">
             <p-panel [header]="question.q_name" [style]="{'text-align':'center'}">
                     <div class="question-detail"><input type="radio" (click)="count(i, 1, $event)" name="choice{{i}}"  [value]=1>{{question.ch_one}}</div>
             </p-panel>
      </template>
</p-dataGrid>

this is my code, when user clicks the radio button count method will call

Comment: and since rows=1, count method will always calls with index i value as 0

Answer (score 6):

I spent over two hour to understand simple solution for my self. As you i was trying to get current page(selected) in pagination menu.
I found this solution for my self, hope this will help you(but i thinking that you don't need it more) and other people whos will try to get same value.

You need to make your dataTable work with lazyLoad

```
        <p-dataTable [totalRecords]="totalItems" [lazy]="true" [rows]="rows" [paginator]="true" (onLazyLoad)="searchCustomersLazy($event)">
        </p-dataTable>
```

and hande event from `(onLazyLoad)` in your func in my case it was `searchCustomersLazy($event)` like this

```
searchCustomersLazy(event) {
    // some code here for example request to API
  let currentPage: number;
    //event.first = First row offset
    //event.rows = Number of rows per page
  currentPage = event.first / event.rows + 1;
  console.log('currentPage = ' + currentPage);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is already given in the PrimeNG DataGrid example:-

**http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datagrid**

just type [paginator]="true" in p-dataGrid so that you can see your paginator on dataGrid

```
<p-dataGrid [value]="cars" [paginator]="true" [rows]="10" (onPage)="onPage($event)">
```

and if you have 9 rows only than it will not display any pagination
so you can show number of rows by changing a value in [rows]

and on ts

```
private onPage(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
```

you will get first & row value like if you are on page number 1
then console result will be

```
Object {first: 0, rows: 10}
```

Comment: That's not what i'am asking, paginator with datagrid working fine but i need to get the current page number to process something in my code,so how to get that current page number?

Comment: @adarsh have you got the solution for this?

Comment: onPage is not an event in datagrid so how you use it to get the current page number?